# Find mutually Edges with Spark and GraphX

Tags: graph, apache-spark, vertices, edges, spark-graphx

I'm really new to spark and graphx. My question is that if i have a graph with some nodes that have mutual(reciprocally) edges between them, i want to select the edges with a good performace. An example:

Source Dst.

> 1          2
>
> 1          3
>
> 1          4
>
> 1          5
>
> 2          1
>
> 2          5
>
> 2          6
>
> 2          7
>
> 3          1

I want to get the result:

> 1          2
>
> 2          1
>
> 1          3
>
> 3          1

The order may be arbitrary. Have anyone an idea how i can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
edges.intersection(edges.map(e => Edge(e.dstId, e.srcId))
```

Note that this compares the `Edge.attr` values as well. If you want to ignore `attr` values, then do this:

```
edges.map(e=> (e.srcId,e.dstId)).intersection(edges.map(e => (e.dstId, e.srcId)))
```